# connectedness and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have sets $T, W \subseteq [0,1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $T\cup W = [0,1]$ and $T,W$ are both non-empty and closed.

We already know that $[0,1]$ is a connected set in $\mathbb{R}$. Knowing all this how do I show that $T\cap W$ is non-empty?

I have come across this assertion in Herstein and Milnor (1953) but I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Following @Mr.Gandalf Sauron's suggestion, I am using the following definition for connectedness: *A connected set is a set that is not disconnected. A disconnected set is one which can be decomposed into non-empty, disjoint, open sets.*

Comment: Well, what is your definition of "connected" ?

Comment: As silver doe says , there are several equivalent definitions of connectedness. For example if $X=T\cup W$ with $T,W$ , closed and disjoint then $X$ is not connected. Or equivalently $T,W$ are open in the above case. But in my opinion a more general definition is that the only subset of $X$ which is both open and closed is $X$ and $\emptyset$ .  Now you need to specify what definition you are using. Most likely this is just a simple excercise to show equivalence of two definitions.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I am following Analysis II - T. Tao for this definition, but a connected set is a set that is not disconnected. A disconnected set is one which can be decomposed into non-empty, disjoint, open sets.

Comment: "A disconnected set is one which can be decomposed into non-empty, disjoint, open sets." Then prove that an equivalent definition is that "a disconnected set is one which can be decomposed into non-empty, disjoint, *closed* sets".

Comment: @VivaanGupta then consider adding that detail in the body of your question. It's impossible for people to mind read and help you with exactly what you want.

Comment: What it is exactly that you want to prove?. Is it what silver doe suggests?. Do you want to prove the equivalence of definitons?.

Comment: Since you know that $[0,1]$ is connected, you assume that 
If such $T$ and $W$ exists such that both are closed non empty sets such that $T\cap W$ is empty. Then $[0,1]\setminus T$ and $[0,1]\setminus W$ are two open sets which are  non-empty and disjoint such that $([0,1]\setminus T)\cup ([0,1]\setminus W)=[0,1]$  . Which contradicts that $[0,1]$ is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T \cap W$ were empty, then they would partition $[0,1]$ into two disjoint closed (and hence also open) subsets, meaning that $[0,1]$ would not be connected.

Note: It's also possible for either $T$ or $W$ to be empty.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "...closed and hence also open subsets..."

Comment: WLOG, T would be the complement of W. Because W is closed, T is open.